# Python Boolean Values

Tags: python, boolean

Why is it that in Python integers and floats are, without being evaluated in a boolean context, equivalent to True? Other data types have to be evaluated via an operator or bool().

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to ask? By maybe adding some code examples.

Comment: `0` and `0.0` don't evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not `True`:

```
>>> print("True" if 1 else "False")
True
>>> print("True" if 0 else "False")
False
>>> print("True" if 0.0 else "False")
False
>>> print("True" if 123.456 else "False")
True
>>> print("True" if "hello" else "False")
True
>>> print("True" if "" else "False")
False
>>> print("True" if [1,2,3] else "False")
True
>>> print("True" if [] else "False")
False
>>> print("True" if [[]] else "False")
True
```

Only non-zero numbers (or non-empty sequences/container types) evaluate to `True`.

Comment: I think you mean non-zero numbers.

Comment: Adding on your answer. `string` can be checked through a similar way. So, it's not only integers and floats.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a use case -

```
>>> bool(2)
True
>>> bool(-3.1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(0.0)
False
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('0')
True
>>> bool('False')
True
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([0])
True
```

In Python, these are `False` -

- The Boolean value `False` itself
- Any numerical value equal to 0 (0, 0.0 but not 2 or -3.1)
- The special value `None`
- Any empty sequence or collection, including the empty string(`''`, but not `'0'` or `'hi'` or `'False'`) and the empty list (`[]`, but not `[1,2, 3]` or `[0]`)

Rest would evaluate to `True`. [Read more](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html).

Answer (score 4):

From Python Documentation 5.1:

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
- any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
- any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

Why?  Because it's handy when iterating through objects, cycling through loops, checking if a value is empty, etc.  Overall, it adds some options to how you write code.

Answer (score 0):

0 is evaluated to False.

```
if 0: 
    assert(0)
```